# CSS3 - Blending Mode between different HTML Elements

Tags: html, css, blending

I have an good idea what the answer is going to be, but I just want to make absolutely sure.

I have two elements, `div.glass` and `div.sound`, both contain a background-image.  Is it possible to set the blending mode to each div so that they interact with each other?  For example:

```css
div.glass,
div.sound {
  width: 597px;
  height: 154px;
  position: absolute;
}
div.glass {
  background: url(glass.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
div.sound {
  background: url(soundwave.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 10;
  blend-mode: multiply;
  top: 50px;
  left: 300px;
}
div.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="glass"></div>
  <div class="sound"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 ways to use blend-modes

When doing it in the same element, the property is background-blend-mode.

But, when doing it with 2 elements. it is mix-blend-mode

```css
div.glass,
div.sound {
  width: 597px;
  height: 154px;
  position: absolute;
}
div.glass {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1200/900) 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
div.sound {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/750) 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 10;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  top: 50px;
  left: 300px;
}
div.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="glass"></div>
  <div class="sound"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the cross-browser compatibility for mix-blend-mode?

Comment: As far as I know, the same that for background-blend-mode. Any modern browser except IE   http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `background-blend-mode` instead of `blend-mode`:

```css
div.glass,
div.sound {
  width: 597px;
  height: 154px;
  position: absolute;
}
div.glass {
  background: url("http://i656.photobucket.com/albums/uu288/dragon-g/glass.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
div.sound {
  background: url("http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/youngjustice/images/e/ee/Sound.png/revision/latest?cb=20130330173251") 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 10;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  top: 50px;
  left: 300px;
}
div.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="glass"></div>
  <div class="sound"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Murphy1976 Check now... Updated the answer. `:D`

Comment: the photobucket image is blocked by my office's firewall...but I added background-blend-mode to my sound div and I'm still getting two flat images.

Comment: @Murphy1976 Also have a look at this! https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Comment: I have looked at that page before, that is why I am wondering if blending-mode can transfer between elements. All of the examples in that page are the blending mode occurring in the same element.

Comment: @Murphy1976 No it needs to be in the same element. http://jsfiddle.net/5fxtx0ap/1/

Comment: @Preveen, That's what I was asking. thank you... I was afraid of that.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I know that this answer doesn't solve your problem and your question doesn't have an answer at all at this point. Will you kindly mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the two backgrounds for a single div. This way, you can use the 'background-blend-mode' property to blend the two images.

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4mgt8occ/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="glass_sound"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.glass_sound {
            width:300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-size: 100%;
        }
.glass_sound {
                background-image: url('https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1430760814266-9c81759e5e55?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&q=75&w=1050'), url('https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1431184052543-809fa8cc9bd6?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&q=75&w=1050');
                background-blend-mode: multiply;
            }
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I wanted to know if two separate elements could inherit the blend-mode, like a div multiplied over another div. this is why I had them separated.

Comment: Could you explain the scenario for this use case? I'm sure there could be a work around.